# Don't understand how this Lambda function works

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new in Kotlin, just learnt about lambda functions couple of days ago.

So, what i understand is:

lets say I have a function which takes lambda function as parameter:

```
class XX
{
    fun addTowNumbers(a:Int , b:Int , action: (Int,Int) -> Int)
    {
        val result = action(a,b)
            println(result)
    }
}
```

and call it like:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>)
{
    val x = XX();
    val myLambda: (Int, Int) -> Int = {x,y ->  x+y}

    x.addTowNumbers(2,5, myLambda)
}
```

But saw a new way today which is below.

lambda function:

```
 val sum: (Int, Int) -> Int = { x, y -> x + y }
```

High level function where lambda function is used as parameter:

```
 fun applyOp(x: Int, y: Int, op: (Int, Int) -> Int): Int = op(x, y)
```

And calls it like:

```
 applyOp(2, 3, sum)
```

So, now my confusion is with the high level function. How is there 2 colons in the parameter

> op: (Int, Int) -> Int): Int = op(x, y)

also, why is there a equal sign?

What is the total lambda parameter doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a function with an *expression body*:

> ```
> fun applyOp(x: Int, y: Int, op: (Int, Int) -> Int): Int = op(x, y)
> ```

You're probably used to seeing functions with a *block body*:

> ```
> fun applyOp(x: Int, y: Int, op: (Int, Int) -> Int): Int {
>     return op(x, y)
> }
> ```

These two are equivalent; the expression body is just a more concise way to write it.

Similarly, these two functions are identical:

```
fun helloWorld(): String {
    return "Hello World!"
}

fun helloWorld(): String = "Hello World!"
```

You can even leave the function type specification off if you use an expression body:

```
fun helloWorld() = "Hello World!"
```

Comment: so, the last Int is return type of the function applyOp() and '=op(x,y)' is what will be called inside the function aka expression body.